# Specify an image depending on phone's screen resolution?

Tags: android, drawable

I would like to know if it's possible to specify more than just drawable-ldpi, drawable-mdpi, drawable-hdpi? I have an image which I want to look nice on all Android phones/tablets. And even if I have 3 versions of this image, on some screens it is very stretched. Is there a possibility to attach the specific image to the view depending on a phone's screen resolution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to achieve that effect using the [new size qualifiers](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#NewQualifiers).

Comment: Thank you very much! Although, it's layout-related in general, I really like it.